# referencing (this) in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have elements being generated by dynamic html, I would like to reference the particular href that is calling the function when one of many may be calling it.

```
<a href="javascript:Foo(this)">Link</a>
```

Does not work when I try to reference $(this). Is there another way to do this or do I have to make dynamic ids?

Comment: Can you make an example of where and how you reference `$(this)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a href="javascript:Foo(this.href)">Link</a>` will work if you want to pass the href.

However, onsomething handlers in the html code are not jqueryish at all.
Give your links a class and setup a live handler:

```
$('.mylink').live('click', function() {
    // do whatever you want with this or $(this) or this.href or $(this).attr('href')
});
```

Comment: Why bring jQuery into an equation where it is absolutely not needed? This is much easier to do, and easier to understand just using vanilla javascript.

Comment: @Sean Kinsey ask the OP... the OP tags jQuery, what do you expect?... :p

Comment: I expect the OP to not know better (than to assume that you need jQuery for this), and I expect those who answer to do know better.

Comment: @Sean - Please read before encouraging outdated practices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @Nick I know exactly what unobtrusive javascript is, and I'm telling you, it has no value as long as the fallback (no js) cannot replicate the intended behavior.  
So please add valid arguments instead of just pointing to a generalized wikipedia article

Comment: @Sean - Since when would no js allow her function to run?  None of this works without javascript...that's a completely invalid argument.

Comment: Exactly :) And hence any reference to unobtrusive javascript is invalid as the premises for calling anything unobtrusive is that it _enhances_ the default behavior instead of _defining_ it.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:Foo(this.href)">Link</a>` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

putting the js parts in the `href` attribute is a bad idea. best practice is adding a handler with `addEventListener` but here you can get away with setting `onclick` directly.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Foo(event);">Link</a>
```

and your function would be like

```
function Foo(e) {

    var a = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // TODO: stuff

    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

so when you click the link, `Foo` is called with the event as a paremeter. the event object has a reference to the source element, either as `target` in standards browsers or `srcElement` in IE. the `preventDefault`/`return false;` combo at the end prevents the browser from "following" the link to #.

edit: on second thought, since you have many links, using jquery to add handlers the recommended way is probably better (although the first solution is still fine).

```
...
<a id="A5" href="#" >Link</a>
<a id="A6" href="#" >Link</a>
<a id="A7" href="#" >Link</a>
...

<script>
$('a').click(Foo);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

No point in using the `javascript:` pseudo protocol handler.
Use

```
<a href="#" onclick="Foo(this);">Link</a>
```

instead.